# rake db:migrate : incompatible library version postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

Not able to run db:migrate in rails because of a postgres error "incompatible library version"?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try with `gem pristine pg`.
If you keep getting the same error with other gems, then try `gem pristine --all`, which it will reinstall all your gems.